# debug cgi c++ application

Tags: c++, debugging, cgi

I am new to `cgi` and have an `cgi` `C++` application to debug.
How can I set up the environment on my developer PC in order to debug in visual studio?

My app supports `GET` and `POST` method but I have no idea what to do to make it start up correctly.

The app is started through a link with some arguments like:

```
myApp.exe?mode=create&name=jack...
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks
juergen

Comment: Are you able to build your application or your build fails ?

Comment: i can build my app. but it terminates because it misses the the the parameters that come with the link. mode and name aren't there and i don't know how to set them

Comment: @juergen - Did you try debugging it then ? If it fails after starting up then you can debug to get to the place where it breaks, which will say why it breaks. Else it is very difficult to predict what is going in your application without more information.

Comment: Post the code for how you get the query string inside the program.

Comment: i found the part where it reads the data. it reads from stdin. i guess thats a dumb questions but: how can i fill stdin at startup? not with command line arguments, thats for sure

Comment: well i could add a debug section in my code and write a text file to stdin. in that text file i store my application parameters from my hyper link.

Comment: i can't write to stdin. how can i set up my stdin so that my app can read the parameters from it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your parameters are usually sent as part of the URL, then they should be found in the QUERY_STRING environment variable. You normally get this by calling `get_env("QUERY_STRING")`.

Before running, try setting the environment variable QUERY_STRING to contain `mode=create&name=jack`